# Unable to copy or use my SQL Server database while my C# app is running

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-express

I am new to SQL Server and stuck with very basic (appears so!) sort of issue. I am accessing my local SQL Server database file through my C# app.

What I want is to be able to create a backup of my local database on ftp server through my C# app whenever I want. But whenever I try to upload the database file (or even copy using windows explorer) I get an error

> Action cannot be completed because file is open in SQL Server

Every time form in my app is loaded I get list of products by calling this function:

```
private void populate_products()
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

    con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;"+
                          "AttachDbFilename=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "myDB.mdf;" +
                          "Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";
    con.Open();

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;

        string cmd1 = "SELECT Name,Cost FROM Product";

        cmd = new SqlCommand(cmd1, con);            
        SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        bool ch = true;

        while (read.Read())
        {
            list_name.Items.Add(read[0].ToString());
            costs.Add(read[1].ToString());
        }

        read.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();    
}
```

As soon as this function is called file can not be copied. Since `con.Close()` is called I wonder why file is still in use.

Even detaching database from SQL Server Management Studio doesn't work. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear connection pools.

Try adding

```
SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
```

at the end of the method.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to create a backup, then upload that rather than your mounted database files.

You can use this SQL command to create a backup:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DATABASENAME] TO DISK = 'c:\path\backup.bak' WITH FORMAT, INIT, STATS = 25
```

Change `DATABASENAME` and `c:\path\backup.bak` as necessary.  You can then pick-up the bak file, and upload from there.